# Value or form.value is undefined

Tags: angular7

I am trying to define undefined values for a angular form as nulls until the form data is entered. I am getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined. Which I know comes from having my values not defined rather then nulls. I have them defined in the file but I am not sure why the form is not picking linking them.

I have tried multiple suggestion from Stackoverflow, Youtube, and The Angular Documents.

Associate.component.ts

```
constructor(private service: AssociateService) { }

  ngOnInit() { //put null check
    this.resetForm();


  }
  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if(form != null)
      form.resetForm();
    this.service.formData = {
      EmployeeID: null,
      FirstName: '',
      MiddleName: '',
      LastName: '',
      EmployeeType: null,
      EmployeeStatus: null,
      EmployeeLevel: null,
      EmployeeRole: null,
      Proactive: false

    }
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    debugger;
    if (form.value.EmployeeID == null)
      this.insertRecord(form);
    else
      this.updateRecord(form)
  }
```

---

Assocaite.component.html

```html
<form #form="ngForm" autocomplete="off">
    <div style="margin-left: 10px">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>EMPLOYEEID</label>
        <input   name="EmployeeID" #EmployeeID=ngModel [(ngModel)]="service.formData.EmployeeID" class="form-control">
    </div>
```

I have the rest of the Html for all the the other formData. Just wanted trim the code as much as possible.

I need form.value.EmployeeID to pull the values of this.service.formData. Any help or guidance would be amazing. I have been stuck on this for 2 days now.

Comment: Try ``form.controlls.value``

Comment: @Abdulrahman controlls is not a type in NgForm. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be:

Step1- Create model object Employee.model.ts

```
export class employee{
 employeeID:number,
 name:string,
 lastName:string,
 ...
 ...
 ...
}
```

Step2: Initialize in component.ts

```
emp:Employee | undefined;
constructor(private service: AssociateService) {
this.emp= new Employee();
}
 onSubmit() {

if (form.valid && this.emp.EmployeeID == undefined)
  this.insertRecord(this.emp);
else
  this.updateRecord(this.emp)
}
```

Step3- Html file finding of model binding

```
<input   name="EmployeeID" #EmployeeID=ngModel 
        [(ngModel)]="emp.EmployeeID" class="form-control">
```